# How to know if UIBarButtonItem is pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have tried numerous options for this code to work but I don't find a proper way. I know that this method works with UIButtons but with UIBarButtonItems it seems is different.

```
@IBOutlet weak var stopOutlet: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBAction func stop(sender: AnyObject) {

    if stopOutlet.selected {

        player.stop()

    } else {

        player.play()

        do {
            try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath))

        } catch {
            print("Unable to play the file. Please try another song")
        }
    }
}
```

The line of code that does not work is the following

```
if stopOutlet.selected
```

Is there any boolean that works with UIBarButtonItems???

Im just starting to learn swift and Xcode so sorry if the question is lame.

Comment: `UIBarButtonItem` doesn't have a "selected" state. You only know it was tapped because its target/action is called.

Comment: I know it doesn't have one. How can I call its target or action in order to get this code working?

Comment: You specify the target and action when you create the bar button item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to maintain some external state which tracks what the last button press did, or better infer it from the the state of the audioPlayer. This state can also be used to drive the text the button displays (play/pause)

Comment: Can you show me an example of how to maintain this external state to track the button in order to perform the "if" statement? Thanks in advance!!